# Как начать выборку столбцов "с и по" в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, которая хранит 140 примерно значений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT * FROM `acc` WHERE `name` = '%s'
```

В этом случае получаю все и сразу.
Но `sscanf` не может потянуть столько.
Каждое прописывать не вариант.
Как сделать запросы например с 1 по 50 колонку и с 51-100, если такое вообще возможно?

```
sscanf(Result, "p<|>ds[32]s[32]dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddffdddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
u,n,k,
PlayerInfo[playerid][pLevel],
PlayerInfo[playerid][pAdmin],
PlayerInfo[playerid][pDonateRank].... и тд примерно до 125шт.
```

Потом не компилируется.

```
fatal error 102: table overflow: "staging buffer"
```

Ответ получаю такой

```
768|Player_Name|12345678|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|1000|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|901|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|170|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|50|0|0|0|3|0|0|0|255|255|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|255|0|1|0|0|-|0|0|0|0|255|255|255|255|255|-1|-1|-1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Comment: только явно перечисляя имена колонок

Comment: Можно подробнее что нужно?

Comment: Автор, объясни, что за задачу ты пытаешься решить с помощью sscanf. Тебе покажут, как это сделать *стандартными* средствами в 100 раз проще.

Comment: выше обновил вопрос

Comment: Поправь меня, если я ошибаюсь. То есть твоя проблема в том, что ты передаешь  массив из РНР в программу на каком-то другом языке, и потом не можешь ее там прочитать? А единственный формат обмена, который пришел тебе в голову - это "через палочку"? А о JSON ты, судя по всему, никогда не слышал?

Answer (score 6):

Это одна из тех задач, которые появляются от недостатка знаний, от попыток найти решение изначально неверно сформулированной проблемы.

**Нет ни одной осмысленной причины выбирать из БД колонки по частям несколькими запросами.** Любой буквальный ответ на этот вопрос будет глупостью.

Единственным правильным ответом будет сказать автору, что так делать не нужно, а его проблема имеет другое решение.

Comment: Последний абзац на Мету бы, он же к вопросу не имеет отношения. А на Мете как раз очень уместно будет такое обсудить.