# функция mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Здесь на сайте нашёл [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2-mysql/720116#comment1084899_720116) и к нему очень интересный комментарий, что функции `mysql_query` не существует. Но я её использую, и она есть в php. Как такое возможно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) функция mysql-query устарела и более не поддерживается.

> Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной функции:
>   mysqli_query()
>   PDO::query()

А Вы, соответственно, используете php версия, которого ниже 7, поэтому Вы ею ещё можете наслаждаться :)

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. Так получается mysql-query лучше не использовать?

Comment: Лучше использовать [Объекты данных PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Comment: У одного из наших коллег из сообщества есть ресурс, доступно объясняющий, что такое PDO, для чего он нужен и как им пользоваться [ссылка](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать